# How to create linear layout divider using ColorDrawable?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, divider, colordrawable

I can create and show image divider using below code in xml;

```
android:divider="@drawable/drawable_name"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

But I want to create color drawable programatically.

I use `linearlayout.setDividerDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));`. But I could not see any divider.

How can I create linear layout divider using ColorDrawable?

Comment: post code of 'colorDrawable'

Comment: Show layout and activity code please.